# overload operator|= with enum class and underlying_type

Tags: c++, enums

I use an enum class for bit operations which was posted here by someone else some years ago. I added operator|= and operator&=. The underlying types would be uint8_t, uint16_t or uint32_t. I could achieve this only by introducing a local variable in the function or by using pointer and cast.

My Questions is: Is it possible to achieve this shorter/less ugly w/o the temporary variable or w/o the pointer and reinterpret_cast?

```
#include <type_traits>
```

Version 1 works with local variable:

```
#define ENUM_FLAG_OPERATOR1(T,X) inline T & operator X (T & lhs, T rhs) { std::underlying_type_t <T> V; V = static_cast<std::underlying_type_t <T>>(lhs); V X static_cast<std::underlying_type_t <T>>(rhs); lhs = (T) V; return  lhs; }
```

Version 2 works with pointer:

```
#define ENUM_FLAG_OPERATOR1(T,X) inline T & operator X (T & lhs, T rhs) {  (*(reinterpret_cast<std::underlying_type_t <T> *>(& lhs))) X static_cast<std::underlying_type_t <T>>(rhs);  return  lhs; }
```

together with:

```
#define ENUM_FLAG_OPERATOR2(T,X) inline T operator X (T lhs, T rhs) { return (T) (static_cast<std::underlying_type_t <T>>(lhs) X static_cast<std::underlying_type_t <T>>(rhs)); }
#define ENUM_FLAGS(T, B) \
enum class T : B; \
inline T operator ~ (T t) { return (T) (~static_cast<std::underlying_type_t <T>>(t)); } \
ENUM_FLAG_OPERATOR2(T,|) \
ENUM_FLAG_OPERATOR2(T,^) \
ENUM_FLAG_OPERATOR2(T,&) \
ENUM_FLAG_OPERATOR1(T,|=) \
ENUM_FLAG_OPERATOR1(T,&=) \
enum class T : B
```

I use it for set bits:

```
ENUM_FLAGS(AutostartFlags, uint8_t)
{
    NO_FLAGS = 0,
    A = 0x01,
    B = 0x02,
    C = 0x10
};
AutostartFlags autostartDone_ = AutostartFlags::NO_FLAGS;
... 
autostartDone_ |= AutostartFlags::B;
```

EDIT:
I use it with C++14. On one system I have only gcc 7.3.0 from 2018. But I am still interested in solutions using more recent C++.

Comment: I'd not use macros for these, what about appropriate template (struct) definitions?

Comment: If I recall correctly, the `reinterpret_cast` is being used in an **undefined behavior** manner.  I thought there was an effort to make that well defined behavior in this case, but I'm not a **language-lawyer** and I haven't been following that effort in WG21.

Comment: Ending up on a value that's not an enum value can be UB. [Lightning Talk: So You Thought C++ Was Weird? Meet Enums - Roth Michaels - CppCon 2021](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SGfk5l85cko)

Comment: The `reinterpret_cast` is definitively an aliasing violation and therefore UB. Probably is fine with `-fno-strict-aliasing` though.

Comment: The `static_cast<...>` can be replaced with `std::to_underlying` in C++23.

Comment: @PepijnKramer It is defined in such a way that exactly the use for flags like shown here works out, except for `~` which may be UB for an enumeration without fixed underlying type or one with underlying type of conversion rank below `int`. (Only the last part can happen here.)

Comment: For information, in our code base operator `|=` is defined this way (C++20): `template<BitMaskEnum T> constexpr force_inline void operator|= (T& v1, T v2) { using type = std::underlying_type_t<T>; v1 = T((type)v1 | (type)v2); }`. Other operators are defined similarly. The C++20 concept `BitMaskEnum` can then be enabled with a macro `#define ENABLE_BITMASK_OPERATORS(enum) template <> struct is_bit_mask_enum<enum> : std::true_type {}`

Comment: It is a stupid corner case ;)

Comment: And actually I had to check the standard again and not even `~` can be UB here with explicit underlying type of low conversion rank, it does however have implementation-defined behavior before C++20.

Comment: Some comments are about undefined behaviour. Note, that enum with a specified base type is used and therefore I cannot see where undefined behaviour could occur if any value is used. I was also not sure about the pointer conversion but note, that the data type remains the underlying type.

Comment: user17732522: where exactly do you think UB could occur?

Comment: πάντα ῥεῖ: I do not exactly know how to convert it into a template w/o having to write much more code if I use it.

Comment: @ErnieMur If you want to answer someone add a `@` in front of their name. Otherwise they will not get a notification about your answer. There is UB because you are accessing the enumeration object through a pointer to its underlying type after the `reinterpret_cast`, which is an aliasing violation causing UB.

Comment: @ErnieMur I though that _additionally_ `~` could cause undefined behavior if the underlying type has conversion rank below `int`, because `~` first promotes the enumeration value to `int`, then invert all bits and convert back to the enumeration type. The value after `~` will be outside the range of the underlying type. I assumed that would cause undefined behavior. However, it is defined to work like integer conversions, which are since C++20 clearly-defined and had implementation-defined behavior for that. Since C++20 it is guaranteed that the additional bits will simply be cut of.

Comment: @ErnieMur There would still be additional UB with `~` if the underlying type was not fixed, in which case it is not allowed to store values larger than the smallest power-of-two larger than the values of all enumerators.

Comment: @user17732522
 You wrote: "There is UB because you are accessing the enumeration object through a pointer to its underlying type after the reinterpret_cast, which is an aliasing violation causing UB." Is it really UB? As the cast is only between the enum and its underying data type, what could happen?

Comment: @ErnieMur It is UB because there is no exception for enumeration types and their underlying types in https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#11.sentence-1. "_what could happen?_": Undefined behavior means that you don't have any guarantees on the behavior of the program as long as the compiler doesn't make any specifically. In particular the compiler may assume that it never happens and optimize accordingly. GCC and Clang have the `-fno-strict-aliasing` compiler flag to disable such optimizations.